# Right use case for bidirectional relationship with very many entity instances

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, associations, jpa-2.0

Is it worth using `@OneToMany` relationship with a 'very-many' side at the collection-valued association at all?

When we have few instances, or strict logical relationship, like `List<OrderLine>` in `Order`, or `Set<Phone>` in `Person` it is all clear that we will do that. But when it comes to holding many instances, as in `Set<Order>` in `Customer` or `List<Event>` in `Company`, a simple operation like `Order#setCustomer()` or `Event#setCompany()` requires that a whole collection of elements be managed by the persistence context. Isn't it too expensive? Or should bidirectional relationships be avoided in these cases?

The consequential part is the cascade setting of these relationships. It is logical to cascade merge/persist functionality of `Customer`/`Company` to its 'children', but won't it be a waste of resources in the end?

The last but not the least is the cascade remove. It clearly fits all four relationships perfectly. But in case we are left with a unidirectional relationship of a single-valued association, we then must remove the children separately by using a query when a parent is deleted?

Right now, I am using bidirectional relationships only when the number of items is quite small and there is a clear parent-child association between the entities. Most of the job is done via a single-valued end (removing `Order`/`Entity` on its own) and via a query once the parent is removed (upon removal of `Customer`/`Company`).

After rereading some books on JPA I started to think that I'm probably not following the right way of using persistence in Java EE applications.

What is your view on using bidirectional relationships with many instances in the collection in a Java EE application in general and how do you manage cascading if you choose a unidirectional relationship in particular?

Answer (score 1):

If the collection is very large, then your solution is probably the best.  You are better off querying for the relationship, than mapping it.  But this will depend on the application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that mapping relationships in both directions is generally good if an entity 'contains', or 'logically owns' the other one, but I refrain from mapping in case there are many entities (50/100+), or the logical relationship is dubious (like mapping a set of users that have some status). But generally I stick to bidirectional ones. If I do not, I call other EJBs to handle the remove operation. Am I doing it correctly enough?

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken the JPA mapping itself doesn't support pagination, so the only way to page data and not lose too much in performance is to query, right? Of course, I'm not speaking of vendor-specific filters, etc.